# Multiple level inheritance for Maven project

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a Maven project (let's call it **project B**) with the following content in its `pom.xml`:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>ui-tests</artifactId>
<name>UI tests</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>net.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

This Maven project is destined to create a JAR used to run some tests. As you can see, it is inheriting from another Maven project (let's call it **project A**).

What I would like to do is create a **project C** which would be inheriting from project B (project A → project B → project C). This would be in order to generate a separate JARs for some tests that should be ran in isolation.

However, I am not sure how to write the corresponding `pom.xml`.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>isolated</artifactId>
<name>Isolated UI tests</name>

<parent>
    <groupId><!-- ??? --></groupId>
    <artifactId>ui-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

What should I put in the `groupId` tag? Also, in the `artifactId` tag, sghould I put `root` (from project A) or `ui-tests` (from project B)?

Answer (score 1):

Your project B has the coordinates:

```
<groupId>net.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>ui-tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

You specified the artifactId yourself and inherited the other coordinates from project A. Therefore, when you want to use project B as parent pom, you need to specify exactly these three coordinates.